# List of memoryviews in Cython

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

I have an existing Python codebase that looks a bit like this:

```
class Lexicon
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self._mv = memoryview(...)

... elsewhere ...

lexicons # list of lexicons
for word in words:
    lexicon_index = get_lexicon_index(word)
    xxx = lexicons[lexicon_index]._mv[word.id]
```

The number of lexicons is small, often just one, but that's only known at runtime.

I'd like to have a list or array of the memoryviews in Cython-space, since I don't need other properties on the lexicons, but I'm having trouble with the type signatures. What's the right way to do this?